# Flip ggdendrogram plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, flip, ggdendro

I'm using a ggdendrogram to plot a dendrogram, but I want to have the labels on the left to make the graph more intuitive. How do I do this? Thanks!!!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)

### Data
countries <- c("UK","AU","SA","CH")
distmatrix <- matrix(c(0.00, 0.16, 1.01, 0.97, 0.16, 0.00, 0.84, 0.79, 1.01, 0.84, 0.00, 1.49, 0.97, 0.79, 1.49, 0.00),
nrow=4,dimnames=list(countries, countries))

### Cluster
hc = hclust(as.dist(distmatrix), method = "ward")

### Plot
ggdendrogram(hc, rotate=TRUE, theme_dendro=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that the code `ggdendrogram` when `rotate=TRUE` does this:

```
if (rotate) {
    p <- p + coord_flip()
    p <- p + scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0.2, 0))
}
```

But you don't want that `scale_y_reverse(.)` to be done. So, one way is for you to do the `coord_flip()` yourself.

```
ggdendrogram(hc, rotate=FALSE, theme_dendro=FALSE) + coord_flip()
```

But, one obvious problem is that the `labels` would't justified properly. And you can't do much within `ggdendrogram()` function because it doesn't allow setting `hjust` and `angle` properties externally.

So, I'd suggest for your case, that you create the `ggplot()` yourself by copying the lines from within `ggdendrogram` function.

```
data <- dendro_data(hc)
p <- ggplot() + geom_segment(data = segment(data), 
              aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", xend = "xend", yend = "yend"))
p <- p + geom_text(data = label(data), 
              aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", label = "label"), hjust = 1, angle = 0)
p + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.2, 0)) + coord_flip()
```

This gives:

[image]

Another way is for you to modify the `ggdendrogram` function to your needs and re-compile it. I think it's much easier to do it this way and is quite what you want as well:

Comment: That's great, really helpful. This is more complex than I thought, great that there is a solution!

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I had in mind when writing `ggdendrogram` - rather than trying to cater for all possible situations, it merely serves as a (hopefully helpful) template to roll your own ggplot solutions.

Comment: In the new dev version of `ggdendro` I have included this orientation as the default in `ggdendrogram`